# Converting SQL to JSON and keeping the null values?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, json

**The issue:**

I'm converting some SQL tables into JSON format and I have some null values which aren't being presented in the format I would like. When there's a null value in my table, it turns into " " when converted to JSON, but I want it to just say null instead of double quotation marks.

**The code:**

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$result = $conn->query("SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname FROM nametable");

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"firstname":"'  . $rs["firstname"] . '",';
    $outp .= '"middlename":"'   . $rs["middlename"]        . '",';
    $outp .= '"lastname":"'   . $rs["lastname"]        . '"}';
}
$outp .="]";
$conn->close();
echo($outp);
```

**The JSON format that I am getting:**

```
[
   {"firstname":"John", "middlename": "Timothy", "lastname":"Doe"} ,
   {"firstname":"Mary", "middlename":"", "lastname":"Jane"}
]
```

**The JSON format that I want:** (the different part is the null after middlename)

```
[
   {"firstname":"John", "middlename":"Timothy", "lastname":"Doe"} ,
   {"firstname":"Mary", "middlename": null, "lastname":"Jane"}
]
```

**Edit: I don't want this:** (because null will be treated as a string)

```
[
   {"firstname":"John", "middlename":"Timothy", "lastname":"Doe"} ,
   {"firstname":"Mary", "middlename":"null", "lastname":"Jane"}
]
```

**What I have tried:**

- I tried editing my query to

  ```
  SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname
  FROM nametable
  WHERE (nametable->>'middlename') is null
  ```

  but it gets buggy and won't run.
- I've also tried

  ```
  SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname 
  FROM nametable 
  FOR JSON AUTO, INCLUDE_NULL_VALUES
  ```

  but it also won't run.

**Final edit: I played around with everyone's suggestions and I made it work with an if/else statement in the middle:**

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$result = $conn->query("SELECT firstname, middlename, lastname FROM nametable");

$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"firstname":"'  . $rs["firstname"] . '",';
    if (is_null($rs['middlename']) == true)
       $outp .= '"middlename":null,';
    else
       $outp .= '"middlename":"'   . $rs["middlename"]        . '",';     
    $outp .= '"lastname":"'   . $rs["lastname"]        . '"}';
}
$outp .="]";
$conn->close();
echo($outp);
```

Comment: Why not use `json_encode()`?

Comment: I used that originally but sometimes I wanted to change the column names in the json file without changing them in the database. I couldn't figure out a way to do that with json_encode so it's why it looks like this.

Comment: Two ways: `SELECT firstname AS somethingelse` or `$outp["somethingelse"] = $rs["firstname"];`

Comment: I see! I will try this. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

Convert your null field to string if you want to want JSON to print NULL instead of blank

```
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
    $outp .= '{"firstname":"'. $rs["firstname"] == null ?"null":$rs["firstname"]. '",';
    $outp .= '"middlename":"'. $rs["middlename"] == null ?"null":$rs["middlename"]. '",';
    $outp .= '"lastname":"'. $rs["lastname"] == null ?"null":$rs["lastname"]. '"}';
}
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Comment: Check your code, the null will end with double quote, and OP don't want this :). Also, use === instead when you compare to null

Comment: Fabien's correct. I do not want `"null"` because I process my JSON file later and null with double quote will be treated as a string instead of an actual null.

Answer (score 0):

Since having null inside the database causes problem, why not store "null" string instead, and when creating the JSON format, use conditional operator to select the real null .This is a sample, how your code suppose look like:

```
$outp = "[";
while($rs = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
if ($outp != "[") {$outp .= ",";}
  $outp .= '{"firstname":"'  . $rs["firstname"] == "null" ? null : $rs["firstname"].'",';
  $outp .= '"middlename":"'   . $rs["middlename"]  == "null" ? null :  $rs["middlename"].'",';
  $outp .= '"lastname":"'   . $rs["lastname"] == "null" ? null : $rs["lastname"].'"}';
}
$outp .="]";
```

Comment: Not sure if I'm typing it wrong or if there's something wrong with my database, but with this solution I get `{"firstname":"Mary", ", "lastname":"Jane"}`

Comment: I didn't get any errors and that's what it displayed, but it's alright because I played around with everyone's code and it's working now in my final edit! Thanks.

Comment: @Cait I figure out that, the null can't be concatenate to string in php.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with some dummy data

```
$db_results = array(
    array('fname'=>'john', 'lname'=>'doe', 'property'=>''),
    array('fname'=>'john', 'lname'=>'doe', 'property'=>''),
    array('fname'=>'john', 'lname'=>'doe', 'property'=>NULL)
);

$output='';
$rowStr = '';
foreach($db_results as $i=>$row) {
    $rowStr="{";
    $rowStr.= '"fname":'.((is_null($row['fname']) || empty($row['fname'])) ? 'null' : '"'.$row['fname'].'"');
    $rowStr.= ',"lname":'.((is_null($row['lname']) || empty($row['lname'])) ? 'null' : '"'.$row['lname'].'"');
    $rowStr.= ',"property":'.((is_null($row['property']) || empty($row['property'])) ? 'null' : '"'.$row['property'].'"');
    $rowStr.='}'; //add a comma here when a condition is met
    $output.= $rowStr;
}

echo '['.$output.']';
```

Comment: This will give me `{"firstname":"Mary", "middlename": "null", "lastname":"Jane"}` and it doesn't work very well because the null gets treated as a string value and not an actual null.